# How to change back color of button

Tags: visual-studio-2010

So I am creating a program and I have one button and need to change the background color from yellow to green and back again for an infinite amount of times. How do I do this?

I can make one button change to one color but I cannot make one button change between two colors.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share the code what you've attempted but not working.

Answer (score 0):

here is an examples to change a button between colors

this will change the color of a button everytime you click it

```
if  Button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 128, 0) then
 Button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255,255,0) 
else
 Button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 128, 0) 
end if
```